# uninitialized constant Doorkeeper::Application (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I'm trying to extend the Doorkeeper::Application module to add some extra validations and relations in `config/initializer/doorkeeper_patch.rb.`
But I'm getting this error:

> uninitialized constant Doorkeeper::Application (NameError)

My code (config/initializer/doorkeeper_patch.rb):

```
Doorkeeper::Application.class_eval do
    ...
end
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'awesome_print', require: 'ap'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'doorkeeper'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'pundit'
# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), 
making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a 
    debugger console
    gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    gem 'rails_best_practices'
    gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end

group :development do
    gem 'rubocop'
    gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running 
      in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
    activerecord (5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.0)
    awesome_print (1.8.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.12)
    bootsnap (1.3.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    code_analyzer (0.4.8)
      sexp_processor
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    doorkeeper (4.3.2)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    factory_bot (4.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_bot_rails (4.10.0)
      factory_bot (~> 4.10.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jaro_winkler (1.5.1)
    json (2.1.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.2)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.4)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.3)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    parallel (1.12.1)
    parser (2.5.1.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (1.0.0)
    powerpack (0.1.2)
    puma (3.11.4)
    pundit (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-test (1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.0)
      actioncable (= 5.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    rails_best_practices (1.19.2)
      activesupport
      code_analyzer (>= 0.4.8)
      erubis
      i18n
      json
      require_all (~> 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    railties (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    require_all (2.0.0)
    rubocop (0.57.2)
      jaro_winkler (~> 1.5.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.5)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.9.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    sexp_processor (4.11.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    unicode-display_width (1.4.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  awesome_print
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  doorkeeper
  factory_bot_rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  puma (~> 3.11)
  pundit
  rails (~> 5.2.0)
  rails_best_practices
  rubocop
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.2
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to do same thing on my project but I didn't face that issue. Could you check typo issue?

Comment: I doubled checked now unfortunately no typos

Comment: what happens when you add a `require 'doorkeeper\application'`?

Comment: It gives the following error:

_ /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- doorkeeper\application (LoadError) _

Comment: just to confirm that you installed gem (`bundle install`) after including it to Gemfile

Comment: Can you include _Gemfile.lock_ in the question?

Comment: @sat's: Yes I have run bundle install and I'm using doorkeeper in authenticaiton normally without any problems

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have updated the question with the Gemfile.lock

Comment: hi @Haytham.Breaka I can able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hi @praaveen, I'm sorry but I didn't get you. So do you mean that you know what the problem is?

Comment: Im saying after your post I tried and able to get the error. Didn't find the solution.@Haytham.Breaka

Comment: I have figured a way to do it. I have made a Doorkeeper module in the initializersand inside this module I inserted the injection of the models and it worked fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'doorkeeper/orm/active_record/application'

Doorkeeper::Application.class_eval do
  # your code here
end
```